# Using httpd as reverse proxy

Tags: apache, proxy, reverse-proxy, httpd.conf

This is the first time I have to do something like this. I'm developing a front end application with some stuff I cannot change - it requests some specific address for the serverside data.

I need to redirect all those requests to say:

https://192.168.1.1:8443/server

to a different address, say

https://192.168.100.100:8443/server

I figured this is a job for Reverse Proxy and google brought me to httpd.

Now I work on Windows 7 machine, I've managed to get Apache24 binaries and started it on default 80 port, 127.0.0.1 says "It works!".

I tried to configure a virtual host but no matter what I do, I cannot get it to redirect.

I'm just trying to test the basic stuff first.

I've enabled required mods:

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
```

I've uncommented following include:

```
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

And inside that file I got this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mytest.com
    ProxyPass /proxy/ http://myip:tomcatport/myapp/
    ProxyPassReverse /proxy/ http://myip:tomcatport/myapp/
</VirtualHost>
```

I've looked through quite a few of tutorials on how to configure it and tried half a dozen different combinations of the same basic things, configured in this VirtualHost, but no matter what I do, I cannot get it to work.

From what I gathered, this configuration should redirect my browser from mytest.com to http://myip:tomcatport/myapp/, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If you want to map requests from mytest.com/ to http://myip:tomcatport/myapp/ then remove /proxy/ from the `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` directives. It should be "/" not "/proxy/".

Comment: @nidhi I tried that and it doesn't work either

Comment: I read your post again. Reverse proxy will not redirect the URL from mytest.com/ to http://myip:tomcatport/myapp/. The URL will still remain mytest.com/ on the browser, only the content will be fetched from http://myip:tomcatport/myapp/. I hope this is what you wish to achieve.

Comment: @nidhi yes, that is what I wish to achieve, I want to fool my system into believing the backend is on the same machine when it actually isn't. However mytest.com loads regular mytest.com website, instead of my app. And visiting 127.0.0.1 now shows 503 Service Unavailable.